# How do you export a Flow type definition that is imported from another file?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Given a type definition that is imported from another module, how do you re-export it?

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

import type * as ExampleType from './ExampleType';

...

// What is the syntax for exporting the type?
// export { ExampleType };
```

Comment: Instead of writing

`import type * as ExampleType from './ExampleType';`

you can write

`import type ExampleType from './ExampleType';`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The simplest form of this question is "how do I export a type alias?" and the simple answer is "with `export type`!"

For your example, you can write

```js
/**
 * @flow
 */

import type * as ExampleType from './ExampleType';
export type { ExampleType };
```

You may ask "why is `ExampleType` a type alias?" Well, when you write

```
type MyTypeAlias = number;
```

You are explicitly creating the type alias `MyTypeAlias` which aliases `number`. And when you write

```
import type { YourTypeAlias } from './YourModule';
```

You are implicitly creating the type alias `YourTypeAlias` which aliases the `YourTypeAlias` export of `YourModule.js`.

Comment: but how do you easily re-export all types in one line?

Comment: According to this post, `export type {ExampleType}` is not a supported syntax. https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Import-Types.html Is the information in the post out of date? Where is this syntax documented? It is not documented in https://flowtype.org/docs/modules.html either.

Comment: FYI, I have filled a related issue with Babel https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5538 regarding the `babel-plugin-transform-flow-comments`.

Comment: For the record: There is an announcement of that syntax on the bottom of the page @Gajus linked to. I tried (Flow 0.46) and it works, that blog post is very old.

Comment: NOTE: `export type * from './foo'` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 16):

The following works nicely

```
export type { Type } from './types';
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is old and throwing warnings on my end. Given the amount of views, here's an updated answer that's compatible with flow 0.10+ .

MyTypes.js:

```
  export type UserID = number;
  export type User = {
    id: UserID,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
  };
```

User.js:

```
  import type {UserID, User} from "MyTypes";

  function getUserID(user: User): UserID {
    return user.id;
  }
```

[source](https://flow.org/blog/2015/02/18/Import-Types/)

Answer (score 2):

I just found a need one-liner to do this for ES6 default classes, building on @locropulenton's answer. Suppose you have

```
// @flow

export default class Restaurants {}
```

in a `Restaurants.js` file. To export it from an `index.js` file in the same directory, do this:

```
export type {default as Restaurants} from './Restaurants';
```